# Elasticsearch: server status 503, Java IO exception

Tags: java, ubuntu, elasticsearch

After I got updated Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10 I had got elasticsearch broken on my PC.
I have tried re-installing `0.90.5`, `0.90.6` versions using `dpkg`, have tried to run server from downloaded 0.90.6 tar.gz. No luck.

Here one of repeated messages of `elasticsearch -f` from extracted tar.gz file:

```
[2013-11-05 19:03:43,769][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Man-Spider] Message not fully read (request) for [14787873] and action [discovery/zen/join/validate], resetting
[2013-11-05 19:03:43,777][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [Man-Spider] failed to send join request to master [[Mad Jack][rnQVBSc0RoWJY4aXXxK-tw][inet[/172.20.46.38:9300]]], reason [org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [Mad Jack][inet[/172.20.46.38:9300]][discovery/zen/join]; org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [Man-Spider][inet[/172.20.44.81:9301]][discovery/zen/join/validate]; java.io.IOException: Expected handle header, got [10]]
```

I have found [similar question without answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588927/elasticsearch-503-error-when-checking-server-status). But still problem is not resolved.

Comment: are you running a cluster or a standalone node/jvm?

Comment: @mconlin yes, single developer machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, in your network, there are others users too who are running elasticsearch. Probably your server is attempting to connect the remote server because, it also might be running with the same cluster name i.e elasticsearch.

Open your config file name `elasticsearch.yml` and change the cluster name to something unique.

```
cluster.name = 'new_name'
```

Restart your server. That, probably might solve your problem