# Graylog connecting to existing elasticsearch shows 503

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog2, graylog

- Graylog v4.0.7
- ElasticSearch v7.7
- MongoDb v4.4

We are setting up Graylog in our kubernetes cluster. Graylog can connect to MongoDB server from another cluster using LB. When we connect our Graylog to ElasticSearch which is in different cluster (using LB e.g. https://myelastic.sample.com:443), logs from the app shows 503. But when we curl some elasticsearch api it shows 200.

This only occurs in graylog pod.

```
Caused by: org.graylog.shaded.elasticsearch7.org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [GET], host [https://myelastic.sample.com:443], URI [/_alias/graylog_deflector?ignore_throttled=false&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open%2Cclosed&allow_no_indices=true], status line [HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable]
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure
    at org.graylog.shaded.elasticsearch7.org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:302) ~[?:?]
    at org.graylog.shaded.elasticsearch7.org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:272) ~[?:?]
    at org.graylog.shaded.elasticsearch7.org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:246) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: you are trying to connect ES on 443 while the default port is 9200 so that way you have configure ES ?

Comment: Hello @HarshManvar, ah yes that was the link given by the department who configured the elasticsearch. We are using existing elasticsearch cluster, and we can curl the elasticsearch api in command line using the same uri. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588927/elasticsearch-503-error-when-checking-server-status

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the fix was, my colleague deleted a red status index in the elasticsearch and everything worked fine